# Negative volume in solids of revolution

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the solid of revolution created by rotating the area bounded between the curves $y=x^{2}-2, y = 0, y = -1$ around the line $y=-1$.

---

I have set up the volume in two methods: double integrals and cylindrical shells, and I get the following result:

$V = \displaystyle\int_{-1}^{0} \displaystyle\int_{-(y+2)^{1/2}}^{(y+2)^{1/2}} \! 2\pi y \, \mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d}y$

And in cylindrical shells:

$V = \displaystyle\int_{-1}^{0} \! 4\pi y(y+2)^{1/2} \, \mathrm{d}y$

Which in turn yields the following result:

$V = 4\pi(\displaystyle\frac{14-16\sqrt{2}}{15})$

However, this result is negative. Is this method the correct way to approach the problem or have I made a mistake? Or is it possible that when dealing with these kind of problems that there is a negative volume? (so is the actual volume simply the negative of this result?)

Comment: The first thing to do in these problems is to draw a picture of the region you're trying to integrate, and indicate which axis you're revolving around on the picture. Then, find the bounds of integration and range of the discs/washers/shells to finish the problem.

Comment: Volume is not negative. The region has been incompletely described.

Comment: I have made a mistake in the formatting, and it is rotating the area bounded by the curves given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cylindrical shells, the radius of the cylinder is $1+y$ not $y$, so replace the $y$ factor with $y+1$

Comment: I realized my mistake. Again, I drew a horrible diagram which somehow told me that the radius was $y$ instead of $y+1$. Thank you and sorry for my carelessness.